# Remmina 1.2 ssh authentication options

Tags: remmina

Remmina version: 1.2.0-rcgit-19 (git rcgit-19)
Running on: Ubuntu 16.04.2

In previous versions that I have used (1.1.2), the options for an ssh connection were:

- Identity file
- Password
- Public Key (Automatic)

Now in this new version there is an extra option: SSH Agent.

With this new version, on a new machine, new install of Ubuntu, neither the SSH Agent or the Public Key (Automatic) seem to be able to use the key from the agent.

The Public Key (Automatic) wants to prompt for the passphrase everytime, unless it is saved in the keychain, and the SSH Agent option produces an error message window with a 'No Entry' sign and '(null)' beside it and an 'OK' button.

With version 1.1.2 the Public Key (Automatic) option picked up the key from the agent without any prompt.

I'm running gpg-agent and can connect in the terminal using ssh from the command line, picking up the loaded key automatically with no problems.

What is the new 'SSH Agent' option for, and how can I get the 'Public Key (Automatic)' option to work as before?

Please note: this is a question about remmina and using keys from the agent, not ssh or using key pairs in general etc.

Comment: I have the same issue with Arch Linux, so it seems to be a problem with Remmina and not a packaging issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: I could have sworn that there were another two comments here, one saying it was a regression from rcgit-18, and one asking for more on the 'SSH Agent' option, but they seem to have disappeared! Oh well....

Comment: Yes, this is an issue I've introduced recently and I'm trying to fix it. You can join the discussion on github if you want/can. Sorry for the inconvenience. If you think I should answer below let me know.